# WordPress: Display particular category on load with filters

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a theme with a portfolio that uses filters (ALL, NEW, OLD) to display categories. However, on load, I wish for a particular ("new") category to be the ONLY category displayed.

Then if a user wishes to see past products, they'd click "OLD" and so on..

Please keep in mind that I would create another portfolio and that portfolio's new items would be displayed only on load at first.

I've attempted to find the answer for hours but I have yet to be able to find it.

Here is the code of the portfolio php page:

```
    <?php
    /**
     * Taxonomy Template for the Portfolios
    */
    ?>
    <?php get_header(); ?>

    <?php

    if ( $post ) :

    $port = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, array('portfolios') );
    $portfolio = $port[0];

    $post_img_width = "";
    $post_img_height = "";

    global $mav_data; // fetch options stored in $mav_data

    $portfolio_order_1 = $mav_data['portfolio_order_1']; // date, title
    $portfolio_order_2 = $mav_data['portfolio_order_2']; // ASC, DESC

    $tax_query[] = array(
        //'taxonomy' => $wp_query->query_vars['taxonomy'],
        'taxonomy' => 'portfolios',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array( $portfolio->slug )
    );

    $args = array(
        'post_type'=> 'project',
        'posts_per_page'=> -1,
        'orderby' => $portfolio_order_1,
        'order' => $portfolio_order_2,
        'tax_query' => $tax_query
    );

    $port_query = new WP_Query($args);

    ?>

    <?php
    $tag_extra_fields = get_option('portfolios_fields');
    $portfolio_layout = $tag_extra_fields[$portfolio->term_id]['_portfolio_layout'];
    ?>
    <section id="content" class="portfolio one-column <?php echo esc_attr( $portfolio_layout ); ?>" role="main">

        <div class="wrapper clearfix">

        <header class="page-header">

            <h1 class="entry-title"><?php echo( $portfolio->name ); ?></h1>

            <?php if ($portfolio->description) { ?><p class="portfolio-header-description"><?php echo( $portfolio->description ); ?></p><?php } ?>

            <?php

            $temp = array();

            foreach ( $posts as $post ) {

                $temp_args = array();

                while ($port_query->have_posts()) : $port_query->the_post(); // the loop begins, we need it here. It's important!!

                $temp_cats = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'project_category'/*, $args*/ );

                if ( $temp_cats ) {
                    foreach ( $temp_cats as $temp_cat ) {
                        if ( ! in_array( $temp_cat->slug, $temp ) ) {
                            $temp[] = $temp_cat->slug;
                            $categories[] = $temp_cat;
                        }
                    }
                }

                endwhile;

            }

            // DAHEX
            $temp = array();

            if(!empty($categories)) {
                foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
                    $temp[] = array ('term_id'=>$category->term_id,'name'=>$category->name,'slug'=>$category->slug,'term_group'=>$category->term_group,'term_taxonomy_id'=>$category->term_taxonomy_id,'taxonomy'=>$category->taxonomy,'description'=> $category->description,'parent'=>$category->parent,'count'=> $category->count);
                }
            }

            usort($temp, array(new Sorter('slug'), 'sort')); // Sorting Array by slug

            $categories = array();
            foreach ( $temp as $category ){
                $categories[] =(object) $category;
            }
            // DAHEX

            if(!empty($categories)) {

                if(!is_wp_error( $categories )){

                    echo( '<ul id="filters" class="option-set">
                    <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="show-all selected">All</a></li>' );

                    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
                        echo '<li><span class="sep">/</span><a href="#' . $category->slug . '" data-filter=".' . $category->slug . '">' . $category->name . '</a></li>';
                    }

                    echo( '</ul> <!-- /end #filters -->' );

                } else {
                    echo '<span class="ooops">';
                    _e( 'Ooops! nothing found...', 'mav_framework' );
                    echo '</span>';
                }
            }
            ?>
        </header> <!-- /end .page-header -->

        <section id="projects">

            <?php
            while ($port_query->have_posts()) : $port_query->the_post(); // the loop begins
            $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'project_category' );
            $terms = $terms == false ? array() : $terms;
            ?>

            <?php
            $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);

            $portfolio_permalink = $custom["project_permalink"][0];
            $portfolio_desc = $custom["project_desc"][0];

            if ( !isset( $lightbox_path ) ) {
                $lightbox_path = '';
            }

            // Prepare Project Image Thumb
            $project_img = $custom["project_img"][0];
            $project_img_ID = $custom['project_img_ID'][0];

            // Need some proof check to ensure that no "notice" is thrown ...
            if ( ! empty( $portfolio ) ) {

                $term_slug = $portfolio->slug;

                if ( isset( $custom["lightbox_path"][0] ) ) {
                    $lightbox_path = $custom["lightbox_path"][0];
                } else {
                    $lightbox_path = '';
                }

                $empty_thumb = '<img class="portfolios_single_thumb portfolio-image" src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/thumb.png" width="' . $post_img_width . '" height="' . $post_img_height . '" alt="' . $post->post_title . '" />';

                if ( isset( $project_img_ID ) ) {

                    if ( is_numeric( $project_img_ID ) ) {

                        $thumb_ID = $project_img_ID;
                        $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image( $thumb_ID, 'mav-thumbnails', false, array( 'class' => 'portfolios_post_image_thumb portfolio-image', 'alt' =>  $post->post_title ) );

                        if ( empty ($thumb) ) {
                            $thumb = $empty_thumb;
                        }

                    } elseif( $project_img_ID != "" ) {

                        $thumb = '<div class="project_iframe_thumb-$term_slug"><iframe width="' . $post_img_width . '" height="' . $post_img_height . '" src="' . $project_img . '" title="' . $project_img_ID . '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>';

                    } else {

                        $thumb = $empty_thumb;

                    }

                } else {
                    $thumb = $empty_thumb;
                }

            }
            ?>

            <article id="project-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="element <?php foreach ($terms as $term) { echo strtolower(preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $term->slug)). ' '; } ?>">

                <?php
                /**
                 * Generate the Project Image (Thumb)
                 */
                if ( $lightbox_path != '' ) { ?>
                <figure class="thumb-container">
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_attr( $lightbox_path ); ?>" data-rel="prettyPhoto" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                        <span class="overlay lightbox"></span>
                        <?php mav_framework_project_label( $post, array( 'portfolios-project-label' ) ); ?>
                        <?php echo( $thumb ); ?>
                    </a>
                </figure> <!-- /end .thumb-container -->
                <?php
                } elseif ($portfolio_permalink) {
                ?>
                <figure class="thumb-container">
                    <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo esc_attr( $portfolio_permalink ); ?>" rel="bookmark">
                        <span class="overlay link"></span>
                        <?php mav_framework_project_label( $post, array( 'portfolios-project-label' ) ); ?>
                        <?php echo( $thumb ); ?>
                    </a>
                </figure> <!-- /end .thumb-container -->
                <?php } else { ?>
                <figure class="thumb-container">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">
                        <span class="overlay">
                            <span class="view"><?php _e( 'View', 'mav_framework' ); ?></span>
                        </span>
                        <?php mav_framework_project_label( $post, array( 'portfolios-project-label' ) ); ?>
                        <?php echo( $thumb ); ?>
                    </a>
                </figure> <!-- /end .thumb-container -->
                <?php } // end Generate the Project Image (Thumb) ?>

                <h2 class="project-title">
                    <?php if ($portfolio_permalink) { ?>
                    <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo esc_url( $portfolio_permalink ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    <?php } ?>
                </h2>

                <?php if ($portfolio_desc) { ?><p class="project-description"><?php echo do_shortcode(stripslashes($portfolio_desc)); ?></p><?php } ?>


                <footer class="entry-meta">

                    <span class="posted-on">
                        <?php _e( '<span class="posted-on-title">Posted on: </span>', 'mav_framework' ); ?><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php /* http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time */ echo get_the_date('F j, Y'); ?></a>
                    </span> <!-- /end .posted-on -->

                    <?php
                    $project_categories = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'project_category');
                    if ($project_categories) { ?>
                    <span class="cat-links">
                        <?php
                            _e( '<span class="cat-links-title">Category: </span>', 'mav_framework' );
                            $project_category = array();
                            foreach($project_categories as $category) {
                                $project_category[] = '<a href="'.get_home_url().'/?project_category=' . $category->slug . '">' . $category->name . '</a>';
                            }
                            echo implode(', ', $project_category);
                        ?>
                    </span> <!-- /end .cat-links -->
                    <?php } ?>

                    <?php // Project Tags
                    $project_tags = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'project_tag');
                    if ($project_tags) {
                        $project_tag = array();
                        foreach($project_tags as $tag) {
                            $project_tag[] = '<a href="'.get_home_url().'/?project_tag=' . $tag->slug . '">' . $tag->name . '</a>';
                        } ?>
                        <span class="tag-links">
                            <?php _e( '<span class="tag-links-title">Tagged: </span>', 'mav_framework' ); ?> <?php echo implode(', ', $project_tag); ?>
                        </span> <!-- /end .tag-links -->
                    <?php } ?>

                </footer> <!-- /end .entry-meta -->

            </article> <!-- /end #project-<?php the_ID(); ?> .element -->

            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

        </section> <!-- /end #projects -->

        </div> <!-- /end .wrapper -->

    </section> <!-- /end #content -->

<?php endif; ?>

<?php
/**
 * Add portfolio bottom quote
 */
if ( $mav_data['portfolio_quote_text'] ) : ?>
<section id="portfolio-quote" class="clearfix">
    <div class="wrapper clearfix">
    <?php get_template_part( 'inc/block_portfolio_quote' ); ?>
    </div> <!-- /end .wrapper -->
</section> <!-- /end #portfolio-quote -->
<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: I find hard to understand what you want. Can you show the link of the working page?

Comment: @nunorbatista Thank you so much for replying. Is it possible to privately message the URL as it is not live yet? Also, here is a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/GCOzjgY.jpg

That is what a user sees when they first land. However, I only wish for projects under the "new" filter to display on landing, so "old" is invisible on landing and only displayed when the "old" filter is pressed. Or "all". But on landing, only items under "new" will display.

Comment: I understood what you want now. Your code is very big, you should divide it sections to make it easier to read. I don't have time to go through it now, I'll do it tomorrow!

Comment: I checked your code and I'll not be able to help you without checking the site. Access my profile, go to my website and fill the form, I'll help you from there.

Comment: @nunorbatista Awesome! I filled out the contact form. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is not related with the Wordpress itself but with the plugin that you, or your theme are using to sort the data.

In this case, it's using [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/), which is what is filtering the results you see on the page.

By addressing the [Isotope's documentation](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html) in terms of filtering, we see that the filters can be done through functions or buttons, in this case we're using a combination of both as we want the data to change while clicking but at the same time it already needs to come filtered, as you requested.

So, to solve the problem, it's one line in the isotope's function file:

```
$container.isotope({
            itemSelector : '.element',
            filter: '.workshops'
        });
```

I just added the last one.

Apart from this, you just need to hack the code you provided in order to add the "selected" class to the button:

```
echo( '<ul id="filters" class="option-set">

                        <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="show-all">All</a></li>' );

                        foreach ( $categories as $category ) { ?>

                        <li>
                            <span class="sep">/</span>
                            <a href="#<?php echo $category->slug; ?>" <?php if($category->slug == 'workshops'): echo 'class="selected"'; endif;?>data-filter=".<?php echo $category->slug; ?>"><?php echo $category->name;?></a>
                        </li>

                        <?php 
                        }

                        echo( '</ul>' );
```

Now some considerations:

1. If you change the slug, this will stop working as it's checking for the class "workshops", if you do it, you need to edit the code provided above;
2. Isotope was masked inside your theme's custom jquery file, which is not a good practice at all, specially for maintenance issues.

Comment: Fantastic! You are an incredible help. Thanks!